# Android-Need publish/Share my game score with an image+some text

Tags: android

I have use share intent like this but I did not bale to find a way of publish my game score with an image please help me??

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType("text/plain");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"I just scored 1000");
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Comming Soon!!");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareCaptionIntent.setType("image/*");

//game image
shareIntent.setData(gameImage);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, gameImage);

//game score
shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "game score")

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share)));
```